# Unnest ragged tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, ragged

I have following `tf.RaggedTensor` `rt`:

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[7592]], [[7592], [2088]], [[7592], [2045], [2236]], [[7592], [2045], [2236], [6358, 16429, 2072]]]>
```

here is the dense version:

```
array([[[ 7592,     0,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0]],

       [[ 7592,     0,     0],
        [ 2088,     0,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0]],

       [[ 7592,     0,     0],
        [ 2045,     0,     0],
        [ 2236,     0,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0]],

       [[ 7592,     0,     0],
        [ 2045,     0,     0],
        [ 2236,     0,     0],
        [ 6358, 16429,  2072]]], dtype=int32)>
```

I need to "`unnest`" `rt` to this:

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[7592], [7592,2088], [7592,2045,2236], [7592,2045,2236,6358, 16429, 2072]]>
```

but I've had no luck with combinations of `tf.concat`, `tf.ragged.map_flat_values` or `tf.squeeze`.

Anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, turns out there's a built-in method:
`rt.merge_dims(1,2)`.